# Selecting one row from Foreign Key in Django

Tags: python, django

I have the following models in Django:

```
class Kingdom(models.Model) :  
    class Meta:  
        ordering = ('kingdom_name', )  
    kingdom_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True, blank=True)  

    def __str__(self) :  
        return self.kingdom_name  

class Phylum_Clade(models.Model) :  
    class Meta:  
        ordering = ('phylum_name', )  
    phylum_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True, blank=True)  
    kingdom = models.ForeignKey(Kingdom, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)  

    def __str__(self) :  
        return self.phylum_name  


class Classe_Clade(models.Model) :  
    class Meta:  
        ordering = ('classe_name', )  
    classe_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)  
    phylum_clade = models.ForeignKey(Phylum_Clade, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)  
    kingdom = models.ForeignKey(Kingdom, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)  


    def __str__(self) :  
        return self.classe_name  


class Ordre(models.Model) :  
    class Meta:  
        ordering = ('ordre_name', )  
    ordre_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)  
    classe_clade = models.ForeignKey(Classe_Clade, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)  
    phylum_clade = models.ForeignKey(Phylum_Clade, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)  
    kingdom = models.ForeignKey(Kingdom, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)  

    def __str__(self) :  
        return self.ordre_name  


class Famille(models.Model) :  
    class Meta:  
        ordering = ('famille_name', )  
    famille_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)  
    ordre = models.ForeignKey(Ordre, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)  
    classe_clade = models.ForeignKey(Classe_Clade, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)  
    phylum_clade = models.ForeignKey(Phylum_Clade, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)  
    kingdom = models.ForeignKey(Kingdom, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)  

    def __str__(self) :  
        return self.famille_name  


class Binomiale(models.Model) :  
    class Meta:  
        ordering = ('binomiale', )  
    nom = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True)  
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True)  
    binomiale = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True)  

    famille = models.ForeignKey(Famille, related_name='famille_names', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)  
    ordre = models.ForeignKey(Ordre, related_name='ordre_names', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)  
    classe_clade = models.ForeignKey(Classe_Clade, related_name='classe_names', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)  
    phylum_clade = models.ForeignKey(Phylum_Clade, related_name='phylum_names', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)  
    kingdom = models.ForeignKey(Kingdom, related_name='kingdom_names', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)  
    image = models.ImageField(blank=False, default='no_picture.png')  
    img_thumbnail = models.ImageField(blank=False, default='no_picture.png')  

    observations = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,  
        through='Observation', related_name='observations')  

    def __str__(self) :  
        return self.binomiale
```

In Views.py I have the following code:

```
class Famille1(OwnerListView):  
    model = Binomiale  
    template_name = 'database/famille1.html'  
    template_name2 = 'database/especes.html'  
    def get(self, request) :  
        strval = request.GET.get("search", False)  
        if strval :  
            query = Q(name__icontains=strval) | Q(nom__icontains=strval)  
            query.add(Q(name__icontains=strval) | Q(nom__icontains=strval), Q.OR)  
            data_list = Binomiale.objects.filter(query).select_related().distinct().order_by('nom')[:12]  
            ctx = {'data_list' : data_list, 'search': strval}  
            return render(request, self.template_name2, ctx)  
        else:  
            if request.user.is_authenticated:  
                famille_list1 = Binomiale.objects.select_related("famille").distinct().order_by("famille__famille_name")[:12]  

        ctx = {'famille_list1' : famille_list1, 'search': strval}  
        return render(request, self.template_name, ctx)
```

In my html file I use the following code:

```
{% if famille_list1 %}  
                <div class="row row-cols-12 g-3">  
                    {% for data in famille_list1 %}  
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-2">  
                            <a class="linkStyles3" href="{% url 'database:data_detail' data.id   %}">{{ data.famille }}</a><br/>  
                            <h6 style="color:black">{{ data.nom }}</h6>  
                            <a href="{% url 'database:data_detail' data.id %}"><img class="img-thumbnail" src="{% get_media_prefix %}{{data.img_thumbnail}}" style="width:50%"></a>  
                        </div>  
                    {% endfor %}  
                </div>  
            {% endif %}  
        </p>
```

The output of this is similar to the following sqlite3 command, and output (partial):

```
sqlite> select famille_name, nom, name, img_thumbnail from database_binomiale inner join database_famille on database_famille.id = database_binomiale.famille_id order by famille_id;

Apidae|Bourdon terreste|Bumble bee|BumbleBee_thumb.jpg  
Apidae|Abeille à miel|Honey bee|HoneyBee_thumb.jpg  
Apidae|Abeille à longue corne|Long Horned Bee|LongHornedBee_thumb.jpg  
Apidae|Bourdon fébrile|Common Eastern Bumble Bee|CommonEasternBumbleBee_thumb.jpg  
Ardeidae|Héron cendré|Grey heron|Heron_thumb.jpg  
Simuliidae|Mouche noire|Black fly|BlackFly_thumb.jpg  
Muscidae|Mouche domestique|House fly|HouseFly_thumb.jpg  
Culicidae|Moustique|Mosquito|Mosquito_thumb.jpg  
Culicidae|Moustiques éléphants|Elephant mosquito|ElephantMosquito_thumb.jpg  
Corvidae|Grand Corbeau|Common Raven|Raven_thumb2.jpg  
Corvidae|Geai bleu|Blue jay|BlueJay_thumb.jpg  
Cardinalidae|Cardinal à poitrine rose|Rose-Breasted Grosbeak|Grosbeak_thumb.jpg  
Cardinalidae|Cardinal rouge|Northern Cardinal|Cardinal_thumb2.jpg  
Mustelidae|Loutre de rivière|North American River Otter|Otter_thumb2.jpg  
Mustelidae|Hermine|Stoat|Stoat_thumb.jpg
```

My problem is that I do not want repeats of each class "Apidae","Cardinalidae","Mustelidae" etc. I want just a single example, with its image to be displayed. I have banged my head against a wall on this for longer than I care to admit.

Can someone help me?

Thankyou!

Comment: It looks like your are interested in `Famille` objects, not `Binomiale` objects.

Comment: I want to use the Famille model to access Family names, but I want these to be connected to the Binomiale table, using its 'nom', 'name' and 'img_thumbnail'.

Comment: I am able to do this, but not to exclude any Binomiale values. If possible, I would like only the first Binomiale values connected to a particular Famille name. That is, only one binomiale, common, nom vulgaire and img_thumbnail per Famille name.

Comment: The only values in the Famille table are names of the taxonomic group 'family.' All other information comes from joining this table with the Binomiale table.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should query on the `Famille` model and thus check the `nom`, `name`, etc. of the *related* `Binomiale` model objects with:

```
data_list = Binomiale.objects.filter(
    Q(famille_names__name__icontains=strval) | Q(famille_names__nom__icontains=strval)
).distinct()
```

The `famille_names__` lookup is due to the value for the [**`related_name=..`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name), which does not make much sense.

---

> **Note**: The [**`related_name=…`** parameter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)
> is the name of the relation in *reverse*, so from the `Famille` model to the `Binomiale`
> model in this case. Therefore it (often) makes not much sense to name it the
> same as the forward relation. You thus might want to consider renaming the <s>`famille_names`</s> relation to `binomales`.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Van Onsem -- I will try your suggestions.